# What is a tone word to describe how someone may feel like they do not belong?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, homework, tone

I have world literature homework, and i have to discuss a shift in tone. A character is feeling like she doesn't belong to any cultural group... help?

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage!  Unfortunately your question does not appear to be a good fit for our Q&A-oriented format, where we are looking for questions which have (at least to some extent) an objectively "right" answer; your question looks like writing advice.  You may want to check out http://writers.stackexchange.com (but do be sure to read the policies and question-asking guidelines there as well!).

Answer (score 2):

You may also consider 'Outcast' or 'Social pariah'

Answer (score 2):

Consider *[alienated](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/alienated)*

> feeling that you do not belong in a particular society, place, or group
>
> *Many single parents feel alienated from society.*
>
> *angry and alienated teenagers*

[*Macmillan*]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you'd consider it a "Tone word" (not sure what that means) but the Miriam Webster online dictionary provides:

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deracinate

Definition of DERACINATE

transitive verb
1
:  uproot
2
:  to remove or separate from a native environment or culture; especially :  to remove the racial or ethnic characteristics or influences from